# c++ Call function of union struct

Tags: c++, struct, virtual, unions

I have nested structs, where the base has a pure virtual function.

(The following examples are a bit pseudo-ish, but describe the purpose)

```
struct Base {
    int id=0;
    virtual std::wstring toString() = 0;
}
    
struct Top1 : public Base {
    id=1;
    int val = 5;
    std::wstring toString() { return L"need to use string stream. id="+id+" val="+val; }
}
    
struct Top2 : public Base {
    id=2;
    std::string val = "Hello!";
    std::wstring toString() { return L"need to use string stream. id="+id+" val="+val; }
}
```

I wish to have a single table for all the different types, so I created this:

```
struct BaseFootprint{
    union{
        Top1 top1;
        Top2 top2;
    }
    
    std::vector<BaseFootprint> data;
```

Calling the function in the following way does not work:

```
for(int i=0;i<data.size;i++){
    std::cwout <<data[i].toString()<< std::endl;;
}
```

I have tried:

```
std::cwout << ((base)data[i]).toString() << std::endl;
```

And:

```
std::cwout << (Top1)data[i].toString() << std::endl;
```

But it always says `data[i]-> empty`.

So, to my disappointment, and not unexpected, the pure virtual function does not point to the correct top function depending on how the struct data is viewed via the union.

As my end product will hold 100s of different top types, I am hoping for a dynamic solution as opposed to making a hard-written selection. A dynamic solution will allow me to add new types without altering the base code, and this is what I hope for.

It would be awesome if there is a way to achieve this as described.

Comment: Why did you put Top1 and Top2 in a union?

Comment: Since you're using hierarchies, why aggregate with unions, i.e. why not `std::vector<Base*>` ? Similarly, since you're using unions, why the hierarchy , especially when there's no pointer to base, to take advantage of virtual dispatching

Comment: fyi [Anonymous unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Anonymous_unions) have even more restrictions than named [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)s

Comment: The reason for the footprint of unions is that the vector is the owner of the memory, ie an array of structs. The ideal process would be to get the pointer of a struct from the vector, interpret that pointer as the base struct, call the function. It needs to be an array of structs to push it into the L1 cache.

Answer (score 5):

Union is not the right tool.
Ignoring the other compiler errors, you need to access particular member of union (e.g. `data[i].top1`) and you cannot access any member except the one that was last written to (which means you would need to somehow remember which one is which in the vector). `std::variant` is a typesafe `union`, but you would still need a lot of boilerplate code to access correct member.

The normal way to use polymorphism in C++ is through pointers:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> data;
    data.push_back(std::make_unique<Top1>());
    data.push_back(std::make_unique<Top2>());
    for (auto& ptr : data)
    {
        std::wcout << ptr->toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"a lot of boilerplate code"_ is a single visitor. As both members have the same name, it can easily look like `std::visit([](auto&& arg){ std::cwout << arg.toString() << std::endl;}, element);`

Comment: Your suggestion would work. However, the reason for the footprint of unions is that the vector is the owner of the memory, ie an array of structs. The ideal process would be to get the pointer of a struct from the vector, interpret that pointer as the base struct, call the function. It needs to be an array of structs to push it into the L1 cache.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having is that I was not calling the constructor for the union objects.

For example...
If the union object needs to be Top1 then its constructor should be called...

```
new (&data[i]->top1) Top1();
```

At the other end the polymorophic methods worked for me with the following changes...

Remove the pure from the base method, like so...

```
virtual std::wstring toString() { return L"Base"; };
```

Add Base to the union, like so...

```
union{
        Base base;
        Top1 top1;
        Top2 top2;
    }
```

The continuous chunk of memory of objects can now be processed, by calling the polymorphic method...

```
for (std::vector<BaseFootprint>::iterator bfi = data.begin(); bfi != data.end(); bfi++) {
std::wcout << (*bfi).base->toString() << std::endl;
};
```

If you have never pushed a continuous chunk of memory of objects to the L1 cache before, you're welcome!